# Rails: PayPal Express Checkout Integration in Localhost

Tags: ruby-on-rails, localhost, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I don't know, where to start. I'm integrating PayPal Express Checkout in my RoR application in my Localhost server.

Yes, I'm using a gem, [merchant-sdk-ruby](https://github.com/paypal/merchant-sdk-ruby).

In this integration, I'm trying to follow this working flow:
[image]

1. set_express_checkout
2. get_express_checkout
3. do_express_checkout

In `set_express_checkout` I'm able to generate `token` successfully and able to redirect to https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token=EC-93W211694E768010D here with my generated token.

Inside the method which generates `token`, I mean in `set_express_checkout`, I had to provide 3 URL.

1. **ReturnUrl**
2. NotifyUrl
3. CancelUrl

Isn't it ReturnUrl (a URL of my application **(which in localhost)** with `token` and `payerID`) in which PayPal redirects after generating Checkout Details?

My Question is:
**Does PayPal redirects in a specific URL of my Application which is hosted on my Local Server?**

Please help to integrate PayPal Express Checkout in my localhost.

Comment: I got my answer here: http://railscasts.com/episodes/142-paypal-notifications?view=comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I got the answer of my question from that [discussion](http://railscasts.com/episodes/142-paypal-notifications?view=comments).

Pointing my localhost to a public domain name using dynamic dns we can test it.
Another solution is to use [localtunnel](http://progrium.com/localtunnel/). It's really a cool service.

Answer (score 2):

You can configure your local app url( Eg: `http://localhost:3000/return` ) in `ReturnURL` field.

Try live sample: https://paypal-sdk-samples.herokuapp.com/merchant/set_express_checkout

Comment: Thanks, Siddick. Yes, I'm integrating with the help of that documentation. But how PayPal able to hit a URL which in my localhost? I think it's not possible.

Comment: It's just a redirect sent to your browser, so as long as your browser can talk to localhost, the return URL will work fine coming from their sandbox.

Comment: This doesn't work for the IPN address though since that's requested from PayPal's servers

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that you first go through the following Railscast episodes first (http://railscasts.com/episodes?search=paypal) to get an idea about the Paypal.

Comment: Thanks @Aditya. Yes, I have checked these out already. And got answer that it's not possible to check it on localhost but we can simulate this.Or making localhost live through static IP and forwarding port. http://railscasts.com/episodes/142-paypal-notifications?view=comments